# WordPress not showing object GoogleMapsAPI without plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3, wordpress-theming

I have  website in WordPress ver. 5.1.1 (OceanWP theme) . I created new template in My library with GoogleMaps API (I have correct API key from Google Platform), I added to CustomJS javascript function initMap() and customCSS for #map object  but after all object google maps not showing on website http://wp.loxx.pl/?oceanwp_library=googlemapsplfr . In debugger and console you can see that website was loaded without errors and we can see that inside google api started.

Any ideas why this crazy wordpress don't showing google object?

If I created simple page from VS developer everything goes fine.

//HTML in my template:

```html
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"> </script>
```

//CustomJS

```
    function initMap() { 
    var laender = "'FR', 'PL'";
                var breitengrad = 53.4708393;
                var laengengrad = 7.4848308;
                var zoomstufe = 4;
    var mapOptions = {
                        // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                        zoom: zoomstufe,

                        scrollwheel: false,
                        draggable: true,

                        // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(breitengrad,laengengrad), // New York

                        // How you would like to style the map. 
                        // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                        styles: [{"stylers":[{"hue":"#1382b9"},{"saturation":45}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"color":"#74c7f1"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]}]
                    };

      var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');          
    //mapElement.style.width = '1900px';
    //mapElement.style.height = '661px';


     // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
     var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

     var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                      query: {
                        select: 'geometry',
                        from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
                        where: 'ISO_2DIGIT IN (' + laender + ')'
                      },
                      styles: [{

                          polygonOptions: {
                            fillColor: "#FF0039",
                            fillOpacity: 0.3,
                            strokeColor: "#FF0039",
                            strokeWeight: "int",
                            strokeOpacity: 0.4
                          }
                        }],
                      map: map,
                      suppressInfoWindows: true
                    });

                    var center;
                    function calculateCenter() {
                      center = map.getCenter();
                    }
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
                      calculateCenter();
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
                      map.setCenter(center);
                    });
               }
```

//CustomCSS

```css
#map { height: 100%; } 
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: I tried it out with my own API and its working. I can see the map with 2 countries highlighted. Is your js-file properly enqueued? Try to output some text in your console to see if the file is recognized at all. => https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/

Comment: Hi, @Kalti, thank you for tips. Now, I added to function.php
`public static function wp_adding_custom_js() {
  // Load Google Maps API
  
  wp_register_script('googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap', array(), '', true);
  
  wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps');
 }`

and `// Load custom JS
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( 'OCEANWP_Theme_Class', 'wp_adding_custom_js' ) );`

but now also doesn't work with additional error that I used api key multiple time...

Comment: Check your "Page Source" if the script exists multiple times. (Windows: Ctrl + U or Mac: cmd + u or enter view-source:url_from_your_page). You might have added the script somewhere else a second time.

Comment: The posted code works ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7ehx3zLk/)). Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Kalti and @geocodezip, . I found solution. Problem was with Wordpress with CSS on the theme, page not recognized the object div id=map, when I changed it to `<div id="map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;"></div>` works fine!

Answer (score -1):

Please try to put the google map script in head section then please check again, may be it will work

Comment: Hi,thanks for answer, adding shortode to the header of page also not work

Comment: i am saying about the script which you set "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps" will must execute before the custom.js, right now it is not executed before the custom.js, can you please place this google map script in the head section

Comment: thanks, but like I wrote above, script was Ok, but in WP for <div> tag was problem.  Question is solved, maps works fine: [link](http://wp.loxx.pl/co-robimy/transport-drobnicowy/europa-wschodnia/)